# How to send an image using Firebase Cloud Messaging with notification using data payload

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am Using FCM for my project and to send a notification for chat when the user is offline I am trying to send a notification with a data payload which contains few parameters to start my chat activity also it needs an image to start but the problem is I have base64 encoded stream and its not getting sent may be because of the limitations of Firebase for a data payload is 4KB so I want to know how else can I send the image.

Comment: @Dhanshri please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327171/user-adding-excessive-bolding-in-otherwise-good-edits - this edit doesn't improve the post in any way.

Comment: Ok,i got it.Thank you.@Zoe

Answer (score 0):

Save image to somewhere in a cloud and send its link.

Comment: somewhere in the sense where?

Comment: You can store a file in firebase storage. https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

Comment: You can use services and apis like [imgur](https://apidocs.imgur.com/), too

Comment: is'nt there any way that i can send the bitmap ?

Comment: I believe there is none. Notifications are not meant to be used like that.